# Remove doubles with no decimal places

Tags: r, regex, data-manipulation

I have a vector:

```
x <- c(0.0, 0.5, 1.000, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.75, 2.0, 2.4, 2.5, 3.0, 74.0)
```

How can I extract only the values of `x` which contain nonzero values after the decimal place? For example, the resultant vector would look like this:

```
c(0.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.75, 2.4, 2.5)
```

Which has removed `0.0`, `1.000`, `2.0`, `3.0`, and `74.0`.

Comment: Don’t use *text* processing to transform *numerical* values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can construct a logical index with `round`

```
x[round(x) != x]
#[1] 0.50 1.50 1.60 1.70 1.75 2.40 2.50
```

Comment: `x[floor(x) != x]` same idea but faster for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

alternatively

```
x[x %% 1 != 0]
#[1] 0.50 1.50 1.60 1.70 1.75 2.40 2.50
```

or

```
x[trunc(x) != x]
#[1] 0.50 1.50 1.60 1.70 1.75 2.40 2.50
```

or

```
x[as.integer(x) != x]
#[1] 0.50 1.50 1.60 1.70 1.75 2.40 2.50
```

or ( now I stop!)

```
x[grepl("\\.[^0]+$",x)]
#[1] 0.50 1.50 1.60 1.70 1.75 2.40 2.50
```

:D

Comment: Why stop? `x[grep(".", as.character(x), fixed = TRUE)]`